# Form field prefix

Tags: php, html

I Have a simple html/php form on my page and i was wondering how can i add a prefix to one of the fields?

Example: if a field acts as email field, i need to have a grey prefix like "example@example.com" and dissapear when i write the email.

Is it possible?

[My Form](http://www.tranceil.co.il/events/welovetrance/)

The field i need prefix on:

```
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="form-field-name"><b>Facebook profile</b></div>
        <input type="text" name="fields[Facebook]" class="required size_half"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually mean 'placeholder', you can use the `placeholder` attribute with modern browsers. For example:

```
<input placeholder="Facebook name" type="text" name="fields[Facebook]" class="required size_half"/>
```

There are plenty of jQuery plugins to fix this on older browsers, for example:

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: Thank you! that did it :) ill accept the answer when the block is over